# Error: Module `@nuxtjs/vuetify` not found

Tags: vue.js, module, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

when i install @nuxtjs/vuetify it's not install it's show the error. see the image

[image]

Comment: require('dotenv').config()
const config = {
  appName: 'Dhamaka',
  copyright: 'dhamakacourier.com'
}
export default {
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
  ],
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: '#E32222',
          formgrey: '#F3F3F3',
          accent2: '#313437'
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

Comment: http://prntscr.com/w2okfu

Comment: @joyonto did you run the npm install command? npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/vuetify

Comment: ohh sorry i just only npm install --save @nuxtjs/vuetify let just check me

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, run this command:

npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/vuetify

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it, the problem was the NODE_ENV when the NODE_ENV is set to production, it doesn't install the dev dependencies. Check the NODE_ENV.

Answer (score -1):

Please, remove your "@ nuxtjs / vuetify" from yours dependencies with the command:

```
 npm uninstall @ nuxtjs / vuetify
```

And then, install the dependencie in dev, with the next command:

```
 npm i @ nuxtjs / vuetify --save-dev
```

Good luck!